# C++ Using default values for parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, default-value

I am new to C++ (from C# background) and I have a function with the following signature

```
 void AddBenchNode(ref_ptr<Group> root ,ref_ptr<Node> benches, bool setAttitude = false, float scale_x =.15, float scale_y =15, float scale_z = 15, int positionx = 250, int positiony = 100, int positionz =0 )
{

}
```

But when I try to call the code as below, I get an error which says function does not take 4 arguments.

```
//then I try to call my function like so
AddBenchNode(root, benches, false, 250);
```

but I instead get the following error message

**error C2660: 'AddBenchNode' : function does not take 3 arguments**

Would appreciate an explanation of how C++ does this instead?

Comment: The default parameters should be declared in the header file, not in the implementation file.

Comment: You should provide a minimal self-contained compiling example everyone can take and try for themselves to see what you see.

Comment: Post full compilation error, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the prototype in your .hpp file. It's probably declared as

```
void AddBenchNode(ref_ptr<Group> root ,ref_ptr<Node> benches, bool setAttitude, 
                  float scale_x, float scale_y, float scale_z, int positionx, 
                  int positiony, int positionz);
```

EDIT: The prototype in the header should be

```
void AddBenchNode(ref_ptr<Group> root ,ref_ptr<Node> benches, bool setAttitude = false, float scale_x =.15, float scale_y =15, float scale_z = 15, int positionx = 250, int positiony = 100, int positionz =0 );
```

And your cpp file should then only have

```
void AddBenchNode(ref_ptr<Group> root ,ref_ptr<Node> benches, bool setAttitude, float scale_x, float scale_y, float scale_z, int positionx, int positiony, int positionz)
{

}
```

That is, the default parameters are in the prototype, not in the actual definition.

Comment: This is the prototype void AddBenchNode(osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group>,osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node>, bool, float, float, float, int, int, int );

Comment: My question is why I am not able to call the same function this way AddBenchNode(root, benches, false, 250);

Comment: +1, but I think your first line should say "declared" and the last line should say "definition". Just picking nits ;-)

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I had it the other way around. Thank you!